# Why $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos{ax}}{I_0(x)}dx$ is exponential for $a\gg 1$?

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, bessel-functions

dear community

I have a problem with integral estimation and hope anyone could help.

The numerical calculation showed me, that integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos{ax}}{I_0(x)}dx$$
(where the $I_0$ is modified Bessel function) depends on $a$ when $a\gg 1$ as $\exp(\gamma a +\beta)$, where $\gamma\simeq -2.4$, $\beta \simeq 2.5$.

I guess, that such a nice dependency comes from some elegant mathematics connected to rapidly oscillating of the cosine function. But I can't understand how to prove it and how to calculate parameters of the exponent analytically.

I tried to find such integral in books with integral tables, but failed too.

[image: The two components of the underintegral-function]

in the graphic I plot both constituents of the underintegral-function.

Maybe there is some common method to solve problems like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the smallest absolute value of a zero of $I_0(z)$ is about $2.4048$.

Comment: $I_0(iz)=J_0(-z)$, where $J_0(z)$ is the Bessel' function of the first kind and has zeros at real $z$. As @wasn'nt me mentioned, the first zero is at $z\approx 2.4$. Close the contour in the upper half-plane:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\cos{ax}}{I_0(x)}dx=\Re\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{iax}}{I_0(x)}dx=\Re\oint\frac{e^{iaz}}{I_0(z)}dz$$
$$=\Re \,2\pi i\sum Res\frac{e^{iaz}}{I_0(z)}=\Re \,2\pi i\sum_k Res\frac{e^{iaz}}{I_0'(z_k)(z-z_k)}=2\pi\sum_k Res\frac{e^{-az}}{J_0'(\hat z_k)(z-\hat z_k)}$$
where $z_k,\, \hat z_k=iz_k$ are the zeros of $I_0, J_0$; $J'_0(z)=\frac{d}{dz}J_0(z)$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Yes, that's what I had in mind, a partial fraction decomposition of $1/I_0(z)$, essentially. It might be interesting to investigate that numerically (should be rather accurate), but I don't have the time, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you a lot!
I still need to remind myself how to calculate residues, but the problem becomes much easier and I hope I'll get it, thanks for your answer